# В чем ошибка программы, которая определяет курс валюты по отношению к рублю?

Tags: javascript

Задача: Написать программу, которая на основании запроса данных с сайта http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp определит курс гонконского доллара к российскому рублю

Написал такой код, но инфу не выводит. Почему?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

     <title>Document</title>

 </head>

 <body>
 
 <div id="usd"></div>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>

 $.getJSON("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp", function(data) {
 
     $('#usd').html(data.Valute.USD.Nominal+" Доллар -> "+ data.Valute.USD.Value+" Рублей");
 
 });
 
 </script>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Какую ошибку пишет в консоле?

Comment: во-первых, CORS, во-вторых, отдается XML, а не json

Comment: 1)Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 2) GET http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: И как сделать, чтобы работало?

Comment: Если просто чтоб потренироваться:
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_val.asp?d=0')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(xmlString => $.parseXML(xmlString))
        .then(data => console.log(data))

Но лучше найдите JSON api и работайте с ним. ИМХО!